# How do I hand draw on canvas with Python?

Tags: python, canvas

I would like to be able to draw on a canvas with Python and record the strokes point by point. That means the user clicks on the canvas, moves the mouse, lifts the mouse button clicks again, ...

So I would like to work with Python similar like I did in the question [How do I hand draw on canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22891827/562769).

How can I do this with Python?

I am NOT looking for a way to manipulate figures / place SVGs / ...

Comment: I assume you are looking for a solution which does not happen inside a web browser? I sugget you take a look PyQt or PySide which are Python bindings for Qt native toolkit.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I have never worked with Python and the web. So it could happen inside of a Web Browser.

Comment: In the web browser you can only run JavaScript. There are theoretical solutions which cross-compile Python to JavaScript, but those are academic exercises. Thus, you should pick one of the native application toolkits for Python.

Comment: Well, JavaScript could do the recording and send it via POST to a Python web server that only listens. That would eventually be the best solution.

Comment: Hmm you don't need real-time? But in the end, it will be much simpler just to learn JavaScript basics and and do it using browser `<canvas>` element. In the order of several magnitudes. You may even find libraries and frameworks suitable for your purposes, with little modification needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Kivy library, one of the startup tutorials on the Kivy website is making a [simple painting app](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

This should work on Windows and Unix based systems including OSX, as well as Android after being packaged by [Bulldozer](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) ([github](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)). You can also make a package for iOS, but it's a little more [complicated](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html)

Comment: Can I use `argparse` with Kivy? When I use it like I am used to, then Kivy seems to "override" the argparse argument parsing.

Comment: I'm not sure how, but google lead me to a kivy program which uses it :http://pythonhosted.org/KiTT/_modules/kitt/kitt.html