# How can I clear the canvas such that a line is always displayed between (0,0) and my mouse coordinates?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am beginning to explore HTML canvas element by creating a simple drawing program:

- When I move my mouse on the canvas, I want a line to be drawn between (0,0) and my mouse coordinates. I only want to render one line at any given time.
- To ensure that only one line is displayed, on mouse move, I clear the context and draw a new line from (0,0) to mouse (x,y).
- The above is not the same as 'free-form' or 'pencil' drawing tool, but a crude form of 'line' tool.

Inside the mouse move event handler, I first do this:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and then do this:

```
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
context.stroke();
```

The problem is, the canvas is not clearing and all lines previously drawn are still shown.

The full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/csenthiltech/7ozsnhoy/

I tried going through the source code of simple drawing programs online and found they too followed a similar approach. But I am not able to get it working. Here are some questions I went through about this topic:

- [Draw on HTML5 Canvas using a mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse)
- [How do I hand draw on canvas with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891827/how-do-i-hand-draw-on-canvas-with-javascript)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://codetheory.in/why-clearrect-might-not-be-clearing-canvas-pixels/)

The reason is that if you do not call context.beginPath() & context.closePath(), stroke() will draw all the previously stored commands.

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.stroke();
```

Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ozsnhoy/9/)

Comment: closePath() serves no purpose here (and it isn't required)